# Is there a unique identifier in MembershipUser, regardless of which provider is being used?

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Is it possible to universally get a GUID or unique identifier out of a MembershipUser, no matter the provider?

Using the SqlMembershipProvider, ProviderUserKey returns a Guid. Using the WindowsMembershipProvider, it returns a 28-byte array.

I need some unique identifier which I can uniformly store regardless of provider.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, the concept of user id is specific to a particular membership provider.  i.e. for SqlMembershipProvider its a GUID, for SimpleMembership its an int.  The Membership API itself does not care as the providerUserKey is of type object.